# How do I author Azure API Management policy to allow either a scope or a role

Tags: oauth, active-directory, azure-api-management, microsoft-identity-platform

I'd like to restrict an API for a set of AD users using scopes and a set of daemon apps using app roles.  However, following Azure APIM policy will check only if both claims are present.   How do I rewrite the below policy to allow EITHER a scope OR an app role to be present in the JWT token:

```
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized">
        <required-claims>
            <claim name="scp" match="any">
                <value>API.Request.Get</value>
            </claim>
            <claim name="roles" match="any">
                <value>API.Request.Get</value>                   
            </claim>
        </required-claims>
    </validate-jwt>
```

Comment: Is  there any progress sir? And does my answer give you some inspiration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tiny Wang for giving me a the sample.  authHeader already contains the token.  Therefore, there is no need to split it further to get the token.  Here is updated one:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-variable name="clientType" value="@{
        bool isAuthorized = false;
        string authHeader = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "");
        
        if (authHeader?.Length == 0) {
            return "No Authorization Header";
        }
        Jwt jwt;
        if (!authHeader.TryParseJwt(out jwt)) {
            return "Parse JWT Token failed";
        }
        bool isPublicClient = jwt.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("azpacr", "null").Equals("0");
        bool isClientSecret = jwt.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("azpacr", "null").Equals("1");
        bool isClientCertificate = jwt.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("azpacr", "null").Equals("2");

        if (isPublicClient) {
            return "Public Client";
        } else if (isClientSecret) {
            return "Client Secret";
        } else if (isClientCertificate) {
            return "Client Certificate";
        }
        return "Unauthorized";
    }" />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("clientType") == "Public Client")">
            <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized by APIM policy." require-expiration-time="false">
                <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantHere/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
                <audiences>
                    <audience>Your audience here</audience>
                </audiences>
                <issuers>
                    <issuer>https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantHere/v2.0</issuer> 
                </issuers>
                <required-claims>
                    <claim name="scp" match="any">
                        <value>API.Request.Get</value>
                    </claim>
                </required-claims>
            </validate-jwt>
            <return-response response-variable-name="existing response variable">
                <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            </return-response>
        </when>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("clientType") == "Client Secret")">
            <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized by APIM policy." require-expiration-time="false">
                <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/your tenant here/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" /> 
                <audiences>
                    <audience>Your Audience Here</audience> 
                </audiences>
                <issuers>
                    <issuer>https://login.microsoftonline.com/Your tenant here/v2.0</issuer> 
                </issuers>
                <required-claims>
                    <claim name="roles" match="any">
                        <value>App.Request.Get</value>
                    </claim>
                </required-claims>
            </validate-jwt>
            <return-response response-variable-name="existing response variable">
                <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            </return-response>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <return-response response-variable-name="existing response variable">
                <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized hhh" />
            </return-response>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</inbound>
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is combine `choose when` and `jwt-validate`, here's my policy, it can choose to validate scp or roles, but I don't know why it can't correctly validate the value, I'm really not an expert in apim.

```
<inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="isScp" value="@{
            string isScp = "false";
            string authHeader = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "");
            if (authHeader?.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] authHeaderParts = authHeader.Split(' ');
                if (authHeaderParts?.Length == 2 && authHeaderParts[0].Equals("Bearer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Jwt jwt;
                    if (authHeaderParts[1].TryParseJwt(out jwt))
                    {
                        if(jwt.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("scp", "null") != "null"){
                            isScp = "true";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return isScp;
        }" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("isScp") == "false")">
                <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Server is unavailable for roles">
                    <required-claims>
                        <claim name="roles" match="any">
                            <value>User.ReadWrite.All</value>
                        </claim>
                    </required-claims>
                </validate-jwt>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Server is unavailable for scp">
                    <required-claims>
                        <claim name="scp" match="any" separator=" ">
                            <value>User.ReadWrite.All</value>
                        </claim>
                    </required-claims>
                </validate-jwt>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
```

By the way, the validation can also write in the code, and not to use `validate-jwt`, that will be :

```
<inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="pass" value="@{
            bool isContainScp = false;
            bool isContainRoles = false;
            string pass = "false";
            string authHeader = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "");
            if (authHeader?.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] authHeaderParts = authHeader.Split(' ');
                if (authHeaderParts?.Length == 2 && authHeaderParts[0].Equals("Bearer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Jwt jwt;
                    if (authHeaderParts[1].TryParseJwt(out jwt))
                    {
                        string tempScp = jwt.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("scp", "null");
                        if(tempScp != "null"){
                            isContainScp = tempScp.Contains("User.ReadWrite.All");
                        }else{
                            //write logic here
                            isContainRoles = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isContainScp || isContainRoles){
                pass = "true";
            }
            return pass;
        }" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault("pass") == "false")">
                <return-response response-variable-name="existing response variable">
                    <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized hhh" />
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <otherwise />
        </choose>
    </inbound>
```

Answer (score 0):

The high road to acheive the roles claim from JWT will be to add 'output-token-variable-name' prperty in validate-jwt policy.
Here is an example (the required claim here is 'emails' but the same idea):

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid." require-scheme="Bearer" output-token-variable-name="jwt">
        <openid-config url="https://csmsorg.b2clogin.com/csmsorg.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_susi_reset_v2" />
        <audiences>
            <audience>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx</audience>
        </audiences>
        <issuers>
            <issuer>https://xxxxxx.b2clogin.com/e748014c-129c-4d13-accc-e5e1bb7c38eb/v2.0/</issuer>
        </issuers>
        <required-claims>
            <claim name="tfp" match="any">
                <value>B2C_1_susi_reset_v2</value>
                <value>B2C_1__SUSI</value>
            </claim>
        </required-claims>
    </validate-jwt>        
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(!((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt"]).Claims["emails"].Contains("xxxxxx@gmail.com"))">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
            </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
</inbound>
```